# Need help to connect a function defined in one file to another file so when I run this file it can display the function defined in former file

Tags: python

I've created 2 python files first named `periodictable` and the other named "project". in `periodictable`, I've defined a function that will print the periodic table image using tkinter. i wish to write a code in the "project" file so that when I run the "project" file it will print the periodic table image. I do not know what code I should write in "project" to perform this task.

this is the code I wrote in "periodic table" file:

```
from tkinter import *
def periodictab():

    window = Tk()
    window.title("image")
    window=Canvas(window, width=880, height=604)
    window.pack()
    image=PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\sony\\Desktop\\yawn\\download.PNG')
    window.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW,  image=image)

    window.mainloop()
periodictab()
```

Comment: *print the periodic table image*? What do you mean by that

Comment: Your files have to all have the `".py"` file name extension attached to them at the end.

Comment: @Sujay: Isn't what they mean by printing it fairly obvious from the code?

Comment: Note that `periodictab()` function will not return until the window with the image in it is closed — and it will be called whenever the `periodictable` module is `import`ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

project.py:

```
from periodictable import periodictab
periodictab()
```